# Xamarin Installation Issues (Android SDK & Windows)

Tags: android, windows, xamarin, xamarin-studio

XamarinInstaller.exe (Picture 1) detects the correct path to Android SDK but alerts for Android SDK 22.0.0 (Picture 2) when I clearly have a higher Android SDK version installed (Picture 3). Does this mean I have to downgrade to Android SDK 22.0.0?

Picture 1:

[image]

Picture 2:

[image]

Picture 3:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

According to the message from Xamarin, you have to install following packages:

```
Android SDK Tools
Android SDK Platform-tools
Android SDK Build-tools
Android API 15
Android API 19
Android API 21
```

and in your pictures, you doesn't have `API 15,21`.

install these package in the `SDK Manager` and try again...